# Detect video Put the detected objects on the green background according to the coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, image-segmentation, yolo

#I use google translation, so the writing may be difficult to understand

As stated in the title, I want to achieve this. But I'm not very skilled yet, I asked chatGPT and Bing, but it's not the same as what I want to achieve

The model is trained using yolov8(model normal)

The problem now is that the output video has only a few bounding boxes distorted in the upper left corner, no cropping/green background/normal detection object

```
import cv2
import torch
import numpy as np

# load model
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model_dict = torch.load('Model_4.pt')
model = model_dict['model']
model = model.to(device).float()
model.eval()

# read video
video_path = 'video.mp4'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# Set the parameters related to the output video
output_path = 'output_video.mp4'
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_path, fourcc, fps, (frame_width, frame_height))

# Defines the green background color
green_color = (0, 255, 0)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        break

    # Convert frame to PyTorch tensor
    frame_tensor = torch.from_numpy(frame).to(device).permute(2, 0, 1).float() / 255.0
    frame_tensor = frame_tensor.unsqueeze(0)

    # Perform object detection
    with torch.no_grad():
        detections, _ = model(frame_tensor)

    # Parsing object detection results
    print(type(detections))
    for i in range(detections.shape[1]):
        detection = detections[0, i]
        class_id = int(detection[4])
        score = float(detection[5])

        if score > 0.8:  # set threshold
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = detection[:4].int()
            label = f'Object {class_id}'

            # crop object image
            object_image = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]

            # Create a green background image
            background_image = np.ones_like(object_image) * green_color

            # Adjust the position according to the object coordinates
            background_image[0:object_image.shape[0], 0:object_image.shape[1]] = object_image

            # place the object image on a green background
            frame[y1:y2, x1:x2] = background_image

    out.write(frame)

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I don’t know how to ask a question for the first time, it may be a bit messy sorry :D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# let's say you have the following xy
x1, y1, x2, y2= 125, 167, 340, 291
# create a bg image
greenBg = np.zeros_like(frame, dtype=np.uint8)+np.asarray([0,255,0], dtype=np.uint8).reshape(1,1,3)
# copy the pixels 
greenBg[y1:y2, x1:x2] = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2].astype(np.uint8)
```